# Passing data into one function to another function in same controller using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, function

i am using two function to store **start** and **stop** timing,
 Using this codes,

```
$scope.start = function(data) {

    $scope.time = {
        id: '',
        mainId: data.id,
        start: ''
    }
    $scope.Mydata = data;

    function startTime() {
        $http.post('/api/timestart', $scope.time).then(function(response) {

        });
    }
    startTime();

}



$scope.stop = function(data) {
    $scope.time = {
        id: '',
        mainId: data.id,
        start: '',
        stop: moment(new Date())
    }


    $scope.Mydata = data;

    function stopTime() {
        $http.post('/api/timestop', $scope.time).then(function(response) {

        });
    }

    stopTime();
}
```

I want to return & pass the start() function data to stop() function.

Passing data into one function to another function in same controller using angularjs .

Answer (score 0):

Just call **`$scope.stop()`**

```
function startTime() {
        $http.post('/api/timestart', $scope.time).then(function(response) {
            $scope.stop(response);
        });
}
```

Comment: you need to debug and see, but you can call your function as above

Comment: The stop() as shows the error response is not defined

Comment: you can check by adding error function like this :$http.post('/api/timestart', $scope.time).then(function(response) { }, function error(response){});

Comment: The stop() as shows this error " Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Answer (score 0):

You have created  functions inside of function. Please remove  function `startTime(){}` & `function stopTime() {}` inside the `$scope.start()` & `$scope.stop()` functions.

Your code should be like

```
$scope.start = function(data) {
$scope.time = {
        id: '',
        mainId: data.id,
        start: ''
    }
    $scope.Mydata = data;

    $http.post('/api/timestart', $scope.time).then(function(response) {
    $scope.stop(response);
     });
}
$scope.stop = function(data) {
    $scope.time = {
        id: '',
        mainId: data.id,
        start: '',
        stop: moment(new Date())
    }
    $scope.Mydata = data;

    $http.post('/api/timestop', $scope.time).then(function(response) {

    });
   }
```

Comment: I want to return a start() function ''response" into stop() function

Comment: That is doing my answer also.

Comment: i want to update stop() time using the start () response.data { id}

Comment: try saving the response from function $scope.start in a global variable such as $rootScope.variable then calling the $scope.stop() and passing it the $rootScope.variable